# Is it possible to create the same apple watch complication with support of watchOS 9 and SmartStack together?

Tags: widgetkit, apple-watch-complication, appintents, watchos-10, watchos-9

I need to create complication for Apple Watch with minimum version of WatchOS 9.0. But in the same time I want to implement Smart Stack and AppIntent features which are only available in WatchOS 10.
Can I provide `AppIntentTimelineProvider` and `TimelineProvider` in one extension or I need to make two different complications for each purpose?

I tried to provide different structures of `TimelineEntry`, `EntryView` etc (one with `@available(watchOS 10, *)` attribute and another for older version) for each purpose but finally it leads to conflict inside `Widget` struct's `WidgetConfiguration` body (because I tried to provide two different `WidgetConfiguration` types depending of watchOS version).

Is there way to make one (or the same) complication for watchOS 9 and watchOS 10 with Smart Stack functionality without duplication in widget gallery?